# Xcode add same view from different controllers using class method

Tags: xcode, class, view, methods

I am using loading indicator with background image and label.

```
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *isLoading;
IBOutlet UIImageView *isLoadingImageView;
IBOutlet UILabel *loadingLabel;
```

In my app this loading set is called like 5 6 times from different controllers. Is there any easy way to write a class like:IndicatorClass and class methods like:showLoadingSet hideLoadingSet to bring this set infront of my view. For example in mapController, i just only want to call [IndicatorClass showLoadingSet] and [IndicatorClass hideLoadingSet].

What I am doing is that I am creating IBOutlets for each controller, it is totally waste of time.

Is there any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a peak at the [`MBLoadingHUD`](http://macindie.com/2011/01/mbprogresshud-when-you-simply-have-to-make-users-wait/) example. It sounds like you are trying to implement something similar to this. If not, you can always see how that class is used.